# Php Encryption Result

Tags: php, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I unforesee the result.

This is my encryption method:

```
const METHOD = "AES-256-ECB";
public $key;

public function encrypt($string,$key){
        return strtr(base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($string, $this::METHOD, hash('sha256', $key, true))), '+/=', '-_,');
}
```

This code generates the $key for encryption.

```
$string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        $max = strlen($string) - 1;
        $token = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++) {
            $token .= $string[mt_rand(0, $max)];
        }
        $key = $token;
```

My question is:
**? &** these signs can the result in?

because I am using the $_GET parameters in.

Comment: I can not get the idea of the question ? can you please paste a functional code?

Comment: I want to say simply this.
$result = strtr(base64_encode(openssl_encrypt("HELLOWORD", "AES-256-ECB", hash('sha256', rand(1000,9999), true))), '+/=', '-_,');

This $result may contain these signs "? &".

Comment: My english not well. Maybe i cant say what i want to say sorry, but looking understandable. :D

Comment: I would say no, the result cannot contain the characters "?" or "&".

Comment: It shouldn't matter because you should be URL Encoding any raw data that you are inserting into a query string anyway.

Comment: James thank you so much. :)

Comment: It's not the point here, but this code isn't secure. The ECB is not safe, [you can see the encrypted penguin](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14487/can-someone-explain-the-ecb-penguin), also anyone can modify the encrypted text. The `mt_rand` is not cryptographically secure, also there's no reason to forces the key to be alphanumeric-only.

Answer (score 1):

No, any output of base64 encode are chars from 0 to 63 only + and / are the non letters or numbers

take a look in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table